# How to run Object_detection_image.py, which is outside my django project?

Tags: django, tensorflow

I will be thankful if someone can help me with the following issue.

I am using windows 10
Django version: 2.1.1 with Python version: 3.5
I have my TensorFlow object detection API, that trained my images which is totally outside of my Django project.

However, I created my Django project after that in the same environment that I had my TensorFlow object detection models.

Both of them with the same (python version: 3.5).
Before creating the Django webpage, I always needed to run my 'Object_detection_image.py' from anaconda prompt line, otherwise, I got an error.
My question is: how I can specify my Object_detection_image.py path directory in the setting.py in Django using anaconda prompt line?
When I write my directory like this: C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection
then how I can use anaconda prompt line in this path? because if I write it like this, it doesn't work. please help me.
Thank you.
[image: my settings.py file]

I did not run it because I have a problem with how to write the path for my TensorFlow project. I thought if they locate in the same environment, I won't get any problem. I mean before creating Django I could not run it directly from the script. I had to use an anaconda prompt line. but now, since i have django i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Please show us the relevant part of your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Also please post the relevant part of the stack trace of your error.